# jQuery select individual li ids to use a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sweetalert

I am trying a script to launch a jQuery alert function (using sweetalert for the alert) which lets a user search iTunes for a software item staying within the alert.

I want to create a similar alert for the other 7 li items using iTunes categories. Additionally I want to put the code in a separate custom.js file (it is for Wordpress) so I would like to find a way to iterate over the items using the different ids to launch the specific search for that particular li item and for that particular term. The search is via a Sweetalert Ajax (promise) call and I am using the Wordpress jQuery not the jQuery one.

The script for the first (and only at the moment) li item/term 'software' works OK on the page but when I transfer it in to a custom js file it does not load. Custom script is loaded at bottom of page below jquery. Sweetalert has to be put at top in head. Assuming I manage to put the function in the custom.js (would it have to be 8 separate functions for the different search terms as it would be the same function but different terms ?) I would like to know which is the best way to approach this overall and would I be better using classes rather than ids ?

```
**html**
<li id="sftw">Search Top Software</li>
```

**custom.js** (currently in html page)

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
     $('#sftw').click(function() {
          swal({
   text: 'Search for software. e.g. "Project Management.',
   content: "input",
   button: {
     text: "Search!",
     closeModal: false,
   },
 })
 .then(name => {
   if (!name) throw null;

   return fetch(`https:itunes.apple.com/search?term=${name}&country=us&entity=software`);
 })
 .then(results => {
   return results.json();
 })
 .then(json => {
   const software = json.results[1];

   if (!software) {
     return swal("No software was found!");
   }

   const name = software.softwareDeveloper;
   const imageURL = software.artworkUrl100;

   swal({
     title: "Top result:",
     text: name,
     icon: imageURL,
   });
 })
 .catch(err => {
   if (err) {
     swal("Oh no!", "The AJAX request failed!", "error");
   } else {
     swal.stopLoading();
     swal.close();
   }
 });
 });
    });
```

It works when I have it on the html page but when moved to custom js file it does not work. ???

Comment: What errors are you receiving in your console? This could be as simple as any dependencies are not being loaded.

Comment: No errors shown, it works fine in page but when moved to custom script it tops working. Console shows scripts loading in this order, <head>sweetalert.js</head><body>jquery.js,custom.js</body>

Comment: I just tried changing the load order to put jquery first but now everything stops including another script I had further down page which was working fine <!-- include jQuery-->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- include custom js -->
    <script src="js/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>

Comment: The on page script only works if I include the external jquery before it ie just under the ul tag, if I move it below the div to before the end </body? tag it stops working, its supposed to work in that position, though ?

Comment: So essentially, as soon as I move anything to external file it stops working.

Comment: Also, I have an anomaly in that although I include sweetalert in the head tag below css, it actually shows up in console as being in the body tag ?

Comment: Try to load `jQuery` before anything that uses its library. Also, it sounds like you are looking at the load order from an inspector. Look in your `Network` tab and watch the load order. One of your dependencies may be loading in conflicting scripts.

Comment: I put them in the right order now and it seems to be loading correctly, Thanks